# How can I split the arrow in the following diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I got a help on drawing this diagram from here

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}
        & P \ar[dl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']
        \ar[d, "f"]     \\
        A \ar[r,twoheadrightarrow,"g" ']   & B  \arrow[r, twoheadrightarrow] & 0
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

But how can I split the arrow as shown below:

?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

That is your third very similar question ... so I estimate that it is time, that you read documentation for the `tikz-cd`package and make yourself more familiar with this package ;-). You need to insert new row between existed:

**Edit:**
Considered is @campa's comment:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}
        & F(S)\mathrlap{{}= P\oplus K} \ar[ddl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']
                            \ar[d,"\pi"]    \\
        & P \ar[d,"F'"]     \\  % <---
M \ar[r,"\varphi" ']   & B  \ar[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but may I suggest `F(S) \mathrlap{{}= P\oplus K}` (with `mathtools`) instead of the `\hspace`? In this way no guessing is needed and the left "triangle" isn't as wide.

Comment: @campa, good idea. Thank you very much!. Considered in edited answer!

Comment: Ok I promise I will thank you!@Zarko

Answer (score 1):

Peraphs in origin the commutative-diagrams is done with `xy` package and the fonts of `mtpro2`.

*PS: Excuse me very much @egreg for the tips that you not like. :-(*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=1pc{
& **[r] \pazocal{F}(S)= P\oplus K \ar[d]^\pi \ar@{-->}[ddl]_{F'} & \\
& B \ar[d]^{f} &  \\ 
M \ar[r]^{\varphi} & N\ar[r]& 0
}
\end{document}
```

[image]